# Use a FOR loop to run function over each column in r

Tags: r

I have several columns of data that I want to use a for loop (specifically a for loop. Please, no answers that don't involve a for loop) to run a function for each column in a matrix.

```
x <- runif(10,0,10)
y <- runif(10,10,20)
z <- runif(10,20,30)

tab <- cbind(x,y,z)


             x        y        z
 [1,] 9.5262742 16.22999 21.93228
 [2,] 5.8183264 14.53771 21.81774
 [3,] 3.9509342 17.36694 22.46594
 [4,] 3.0245614 19.46411 25.80411
 [5,] 5.0284351 13.89636 21.61767
 [6,] 3.0291715 17.50267 26.28110
 [7,] 8.4727471 16.77365 27.60535
 [8,] 3.3816903 15.23395 22.01265
 [9,] 0.3182083 13.97575 29.25909
[10,] 2.6499290 16.71129 27.05160



for (i in 1:ncol(tab)){
     print(mean(i))
}
```

I have almost no familiarity with R and have had trouble finding a solution that specifically uses a for loop to run a function and output a result per column.

Comment: Try `print(mean(tab[, i]))`. You have to pass the function the *column*, not the column *index*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, strictly using a for loop, I think this would do what you want to!

```
x <- runif(10,0,10)
y <- runif(10,10,20)
z <- runif(10,20,30)

tab <- cbind(x,y,z)

for (i in 1:ncol(tab)){
     print(mean(tab[, i]))
}
```

You need to index the matrix by using `[row, column]`. When you want to select all rows for a specific column (which is your case), just leave the row field empty. So that's why you have to use `[, i]`, where `i` is your index.